# How to Get a File From Web Center Content using java. ?? using http protocol

Tags: content-management-system, webcenter

I am trying to get list of files for a user from oracle web center content.
Using RIDC in Http 
Can any one help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/doc.1111/e10807/c23_ridc.htm#CSSDK840 - check out using services.

Comment: Service Guide is located [here](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wcc/CSSRG/GUID-5443AA3F-DDE9-4E91-BB41-93651ABE7FFF.htm).

[This blog post](https://jonathanhult.com/blog/2012/12/ridc-examples/) has lots of good examples on how to do many actions via RIDC.

Comment: thank you, i have done it using the same documentation